# Install Android driver for Ollee tablet

Tags: android, debugging, adb, drivers

I may have made a mistake but I purchased a $99 Ollee brand Android tablet (M16071A) for use with debugging apps. It runs Android 5.1.1.
I can't get it to show in ADB when I run adb devices and in Windows Device Manager it always shows as having no driver.
The hardware states it runs an Intel Atom processor.

Here's what I've done so far:
1) Turned on USB debugging on the device
2) Installed latest Google USB Driver - didn't work.
3) Located the Intel driver (1.10 I think it was) and installed - didn't work
4) For each attempt I tried with the Tablet in both MTP and non-MTP modes

I have tried navigating to both drivers via the 'manually install a driver' process, selecting the location on my drive. Neither worked.

I'm running out of ideas and everything I've read is just a variation of the above.
I'm beginning to think I bought a tablet that simply doesn't work for debugging.

Are there any other steps I can try to get this working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-make-truly-universal-adb-and.html

Comment: Thank you Alex P, worked like a charm.For those that find this question I also had to disable the driver security from the Troubleshooter menu in system settings (hold shift while clicking restart to get there). But otherwise a working solution :)